# When upload files to Amazon S3, Django raise OSError: Permission denied

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I use [django-s3-folder-storage](https://github.com/jamstooks/django-s3-folder-storage) to integrate S3 in my Django project, it is OK when I run `python manage.py collectstatic` to upload the static files to the bucket, but when I try to upload a image to the bucket in the admin site, it raise the error `Permission denied`:

```
OSError at /admin/picture/picture/1/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/draw_share_picture'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/picture/picture/1/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/draw_share_picture'
Exception Location: /home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python2.7/os.py in makedirs, line 157
Python Executable:  /home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/drawShare',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/liquidluck-0.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/houdini.py-0.1.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/misaka-1.0.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.9.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/drawShare',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11.egg-info',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ragnarok/Projects/drawshare/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Why?

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions to write files in '/media/draw_share_picture' as the user from which you run that?

Comment: @marius_5 How to set up the permisson? In the S3 Management Console, I can upload the files，but upload files through Django is not work

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to get this working, Ragnarok? Try running the [django-s3-folder-storage](https://github.com/jamstooks/django-s3-folder-storage) tests from within your app and let me know what you find.

```
python manage.py test s3_folder_storage
```